# How to get Custom input from controller of TextField?

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, texteditingcontroller

#dart, #Flutter, #Arrays, #Android #Form, #Custom input from TextField.
This is what I'm trying to do, but I'm sure it's wrong.
List _numController =_controller=List();

Comment: Please add some more context to the question. It is unclear as to what you want to achieve. Welcome to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you would like just the text value of the controller?
_numController.text

Comment: Yes, the text value of the controller but in Array/List format, particularly growable list. I want to accept data as a form of a list., for example "allDef": [
   
 "Definition one",
 "Definition two",
 "Definition Three"

  ]

Comment: @SamiShegga I suggest you use regex to detect spaces and to add text to a list to the controller listener